# Why isn't Tony Stark injured or killed while he repairing Helicarrier rotor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, the-avengers-2012

When he moves in a circular motion very fast, there are large G-Forces acting on his body, even while he is wearing his suit.

This is similar to being in a G-Force simulator.

or like when you are in car that is turning left very fast.

Does his suit have ability to protect him from this G-Force? If it does, how does it work ?

Comment: He gets shot out of the sky, slammed into the ground, does incredibly tight turns -- in fact he does all kind of impossible things -- at the end of the day it is still a _comic book_ movie, **not** *hard* sci-fi. Suspension of Disbelief is required.

Comment: An interesting question with a perfect use of tags! But unfortunately it has already been asked on site.

Comment: Sorry, when I ask this question, it doesn't show that relate question.